# Auto focus question title input while opening a new question

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, editor

After pressing the button "new question" the page is redirected and there are two input fields:

1. Title
2. Body

The question opener is probably willing to write a title first.

I think that the title input field should be auto focused right after page redirect, so the question opener will be able to start writing the question title immediatly.

Comment: I disagree: a good title reflects what is in your post. First write your entire question and then summarize it with a good title is advice I've seen given more than once on SE. Having the UI reflect that advice is good.

Comment: I write my titles first so that potential duplicate questions appear. These often answer my question before I ask a new one.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think we should have this feature.

Not everyone writes the title first. I personally always write the tags first, then the title. And anyway, if the user is willing to write an entire question, they should be able to spare a click to start entering the title (or whichever section they chose to start with).